# Why do the C++11 std::initializer_list constructor overloading rules exist?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I can't seem to think of nor find a justification for the following code:

```
std::vector<int> a{1,2} // calls (7)
std::vector<int> a(1,2) // calls (2)

// constructors from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); // (7)

explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()); // (2)
```

Different functions are called based on which method of construction you use (`{}` vs `()`) and this seems extremely perverse to me. Why is `std::initializer_list` preferred to other functions that would otherwise perfectly match the given parameters? <s>I know that constructor `2` above was deprecated in C++11, presumably because of this change, but I still cannot reason about *why* this is the case</s>. The only benefit I can see for this behaviour is that you can initialize a container with specific values and only require a single pair of braces; `std::vector<int> a{1,2}` vs `std::vector<int> a{{1,2}}`. But, to me at least, this certainly doesn't outweight the ambiguity and the changes to overload resolution that this has imposed. According to Scott Meyers in Effective Modern C++, `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` need to explicitly state which form is used for construction as part of their interface (because of the overload resolution). That seems ridiculous to me.

I concede that I must be missing something, but I'm just not sure *what* it is. Please note that I just used `std::vector` as an example and I'm asking about the feature in general.

Comment: It would feel equally weird if  `std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};`, `std::vector<int> a{1,2,3,4};`, `std::vector<int> a{1,2,3,4,5};` all call the initializer list constructor but `std::vector<int> a{1,2};` doesn't.

Comment: @T.C. Which is why I'd argue it should be `std::vector<int> a{{1,2,3}}` instead of giving preference to `std::initializer_list` constructors.

Comment: Also, I have no idea why you think #2 is deprecated. It isn't.

Comment: @T.C. I have no authoritative source for the deprecation remark, but I notice that it is listed as "Until C++11" at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector. I took that to mean it was deprecated.

Comment: Ah, the C++03 signature was split into two in C++11. The justification for the original design choice can be found in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2100.pdf

Comment: @user1520427 The default argument was removed in C++11, and the following constructor that takes a count was added. Together they emulate the previous single constructor. I believe the change was made so that you could initialize the `vector` with `count` instances of a non-copyable type.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite funny with C++11: the reason for that is that braced arguments don't have a type. But there is a exception to this, and why it exist is not clear to me: the "auto" variable is the only one allowed to treat braced arguments implicitly as a initializer list. But it does not allow this initializer list to be returned if you have a auto function type.

Now, you are right: a benefit of initializer lists is that you can initialize a container with specific values. And this is a huge benefit worth the change!

Before initializer lists, crafting a template that allowed you to initialize each class inside a container with a different value required draconian solutions, like receiving a std::vector with each value, or constructing a "empty" template class, and punching each value afterwards.

Another thing is that initializer lists allow you to create variadic functions for C++ in a safer way than using this dreaded `<cstdarg>` imported from C. (albeit variadic template do better on this)

Want to play with combinations a little?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;


vector<int> func (const vector<int> &a) { //works
//auto func (const vector<int> &a) -> vector<int> { //works
//auto func (const vector<int> &a) { //don't even compile, "returns a initializer list" error
    for (int i: a) {
        cout << "My " << i << endl;
    }

    return {20 , 30};
}

int main()
{
    //play with anonymous functions
    auto y = [ ](vector<int> e) { return e; }; //works
    vector<int> x = y({20, 30});
    //auto y = [ ](){ return {20, 30}; }; //don't even compile, "returns a initializer list" error
    //vector<int> x = y();

    //play with initialization
    //vector<int> x = {2,2,20,30}; //works
    //vector<int> x{2,2,20,30}; //works
    //auto x = vector<int>{2,2,20,30}; //works
    //Bellow, a common mistake of people initializing a int to a auto, like auto x = { 1 }
    //auto x = {2,2,20,30}; //wrong, but compiles, its a initializer list
    //auto x{2,2,20,30}; //wrong, but compiles, its a initializer list

    //Play with return types
    //vector<int> x = func(vector<int>(2,2));  //works only with vector<int> and auto with trailing type
    //vector<int> x(func(vector<int>(2,2))); //works only with vector<int> and auto with trailing type
    //vector<int> x{func(vector<int>(2,2))}; //works only with vector<int> and auto with trailing type
    //auto x = func(vector<int>(2,2));  //works only with vector<int> and auto with trailing type
    //auto x(func(vector<int>(2,2))); //works only with vector<int> and auto with trailing type

    cout << typeid(x).name() << endl;
    for (int i: x) {
        cout << "My " << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, and I suppose it goes someway to explaining why we end up with this behaviour (because braced arguments don't have a type). I certainly think that it's unfortunate that the standard's committee didn't recognize this issue and, instead of handling `std::initializer_list` different for overload resolution, I think they should be gone for a "double brace" solution. I can't see why they'd intentionally *want* this behaviour, though. Uniform initialization could've been so elegant.